# SQL Exception SQL0206: Column or global variable is not found

Tags: sql, vb.net, ibm-midrange

I connected to the database, and want to get some data. However, got the SQL Exception said that SQL0206: Column or global variable ADDDATE not found.

Here's the related code:

```vb
Function ConnectToiSeries() As Boolean
        Dim conSQL As String
        conSQL = "Provider = IBMDA400; Data Source = xxxxxxx; User ID = xxxxx; Password = xxxxxxx"
        coniseries.ConnectionTimeout = 30
        coniseries.Open(conSQL)
        If coniseries.State <> ADODB.ObjectStateEnum.adStateOpen Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error, Try Again.")
            Return False
            Exit Function
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Connected.")
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

Function GetDocuments(ByRef ClientRS as Adodb.recordset) As Boolean
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim ClientID As String
        Dim AttachmentName As String
        Dim Status As String
        Dim AdditionalFile As String
        Dim SQLStm As String

        If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim s As String = ""
        For i = 0 To (CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1)
            s = s + "No." & (i + 1).ToString & ":" & CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i).ToString & ControlChars.CrLf
            MessageBox.Show("You are Choosing:" & ControlChars.CrLf & s)
            Dim SQLStm As String
            SQLStm = "Select APFIVCCLA.APP, APFIVCCLA.CLIENT, APFIVCCLA.CLIENTID, APFATTACH.ATTTYP, APFATTACH.ATTPATHNAM, APFIVCCLA.INCSPTDOC, APFATTACH.ADDDATE" &
            ControlChars.CrLf & "From CPASDLIB.APFATTACH, CPASDLIB.APFIVCCLA" & ControlChars.CrLf &
            "Where APFIVCCLA.App = 'Simple Legal' And APFIVCCLA.ATTKEY = '" & CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i) &
            "' AND APFIVCCLA.Client = APFATTACH.ATTKEY And APFATTACH.ADDDATE = '" & Rundate & "'" & ControlChars.CrLf & " Order by APFIVCCLA.Client"
            ClientRS.Open(SQLStm, coniseries)
```

The SQLStm sentences can be run, and can get results, but don't know why not work for this program.

Here's the full Error Message:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in
> SLBS.exe An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SLBS.exe
>
> SQL0206: Column or global variable ADDDATE not found. Cause . . . . .
> :   ADDDATE was not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not
> found as a global variable in *N. If the table is *N, ADDDATE is not a
> column of any table or view that can be referenced. Recovery  . . . :
> Do one of the following and try the request again: -- Ensure that the
> column and table names are specified correctly in the statement. -- If
> this is a SELECT statement, ensure that all the required tables were
> named in the FROM clause. -- If the column was intended to be a
> correlated reference, qualify the column with the correct table
> designator. -- If the column was intended to be a global variable,
> qualify the name with the schema where the global variable exists or
> ensure the schema is in the path.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory. `ADDDATE` is not found in either file. Can you display the value of `SQLSTM` that is causing your error message? The value in the variable, not what you have in the code.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Hi, thanks for replying. I have a datetimepicker on my form, so I convert the value into 'yyyyMMdd' which matches to the type of ADDDATE. And Here's the SQLStm value: "Select APFIVCCLA.APP, APFIVCCLA.CLIENT, APFIVCCLA.CLIENTID, APFATTACH.ATTTYP, APFATTACH.ATTPATHNAM, APFIVCCLA.INCSPTDOC, APFATTACH.ADDDATE" & vbCrLf & "From CPASDLIB.APFATTACH, CPASDLIB.APFIVCCLA" & vbCrLf & "Where APFIVCCLA.App = 'Simple Legal' And APFATTACH.ATTKEY = 'PALL' AND APFIVCCLA.Client = APFATTACH.ATTKEY And APFATTACH.ADDDATE = '20180103'" & vbCrLf & " Order by APFIVCCLA.Client".

Comment: This is obviously hand typed. Look a the statement in a debugger. You will likely find a spelling error or some data introduced error.

Comment: BTW, this is an injection vulnerability as it stands

Comment: Is there a particular reason to add CRLF into SQLStm?  Is the resulting statement being shown to the end user or something like that?  Because IBM i doesn't care about formatting, and I'm wondering if there's a translation issue between ASCII (VB) and EBCDIC (IBM i) that's causing the problem.